# ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server not supported

Tags: sql-server, windows, odbc, connection-string

I have a windows 10 machine that I need to set an odbc connection to sql server.  When adding the new connection in odbc, there is no odbc driver for SQL Server, so I went and downloaded it from Microsoft both versions and  and when I try to install it I receive an error of the following:

[Microsoft_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mXmc.png)

Comment: what is unclear in the message "is not supported on this operational system" ?

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot install and use a newer ODBC driver that's supported?

Comment: ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server is only [supported on Windows Vista and Windows 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-ver16#supported-operating-systems) desktop operating systems. Have you tried downloading a more recent version that's supported on Windows 10?